# Bootstrap less - override entire class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using the Bootstrap less files. I would rather not modify them directly, since this seems to be bad practice. *The only file I am editing is `bootstrap.less` since I need to add in override classes.*

In `type.less` I want to modify this:

```
.page-header {
  padding-bottom: ((@line-height-computed / 2) - 1);
  margin: (@line-height-computed * 2) 0 @line-height-computed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid @page-header-border-color;
}
```

So I have created a new `_type.less` containing this:

```
.page-header {
  background: blue;
}
```

This is referenced in the main `bootstrap.less` file:

```
@import "type.less";
@import "../bootstrap-custom/_type.less";
```

The problem I have is that the compiler outputs both classes to `bootstrap.css` - I want to override the original so that it only uses my implementation instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call your less in the main bootstrap.less, call the bootstrap.less at the top of your less file.

Also you will need to overwrite every single definition in .page-header

```
.page-header {
     padding-bottom: 0;
     margin: 0;
     border-bottom: none;
     background: blue;
   }
```

Comment: So less does not have a mechanism whereby you can override the entire class with your own implementation?

Comment: Sadly no, Less works exactly as CSS in that regard. If you redeclare a class in Less, it will output both classes into the CSS- if the properties from the first declaration aren't overwritten, they will merge in the result output (browser). If the properties are overwritten the class that gets declared last 'wins'. This is why the order in which the files are called upon is also important. If he calls his own less on the top of the original bootstrap less, it will be overwritten by anything the bootstrap.less used, as his less will be inserted before the bootstrap less.

Comment: For some weird reason I can't edit my comment anymore - by 'he' I meant you of course, somehow I did not realize you were the one who asked the question. My apologies for talking to you in third person. I'm very sorry.