# Bootstrap - How to overwrite css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I am trying to override the standard behavior of bootstrap

```
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
 }
```

But whatever I do my css definitions are getting ignored.
I try the following in the header.less:

```css
#navbar .nav > li{

  @media @tablet {

  }
  @media @normal {
    display:inline !important;
  }
  @media @wide {
    display:inline !important;
  }
}
```

Everything (`less`->`css`) compiles fine... and I see that my browsers code inspector css is getting overridden/ ignored.

Where do I define such css statement in bootstrap so they don't get ignored?

Thanks
Moritz

Comment: Yes thanks. Corrected it. Problem still the same.

Comment: I guess you need to demo the issue. We can't debug code we haven't seen. Onle thing though...does the navbar *really* have an **ID** of `nabvar`? I would have thought it would have a class instead of an ID.

Comment: which file are you loading first `bootstrap.css` or your `style.css` if  you load bottstrap first than it will be override but if you load your style.css first than i think it will not

Comment: OK. I found the problem. For some weird reason Bootstrap also defines that the inner a tag has a display:block; style as well. 

After setting this one to inline !important I was able to alter the output.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try **custom.css** file for your customs styles....
It will help you to override the default styles.

Answer (score -1):

Don't call your less in the main bootstrap.less, call the bootstrap.less at the top of your less file.

Also you will need to overwrite every single definition in .page-header

For reference go through the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673941/bootstrap-less-override-entire-class) .

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes